Trying to Automate Comparison between 2 Columns in Excel using Python
I am trying to automate the find feature in excel that uses the contain functionality. I want to identify if a value is present in a string of text. For example a description field. If it finds that the cell contains the value within the cell, then I want the code to add found in column H. I am not looking for an exact match, as the searchName should only be a small portion of the value in the data frame. Everything comes up and runs, but all the values in column H are indicated as not found. I have included my code below.
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

# Load the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Code/Python/List of Parts in SAP.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Parts']

# Read the data from the specified sheet and column
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Code/Python/List of Parts in SAP.xlsx', sheet_name='BE01', usecols=['Description'])
#print(df)

# Iterate over rows and update the 'Found' or 'Not Found' value
for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    searchName = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    if searchName in df['Description'].values:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = 'Found'
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = 'Not Found'

# Save the updated workbook
wb.save('updated List of Parts in SAP.xlsx')

I have tried changing the
searchName = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
to
searchName in sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
This however results in a NameError: name 'searchName' is not defined. I have also tried defining the searchName as a string, thinking that maybe the data types are not the same, which is why everything results in Not Found.
The below picture indicates an object I know is contained in the description of the tab BE01, but the text produced is not found. Which can be seen to the far right of the screenshot included.
Found Object



ITEM ID
DESCRIPTION
QTY
PRICE
UOM
AVAILBILITY
Group




H25136
STRETCH WRAP ROLL
1
$36.15
ROLL
STOCK
5



Highlighted in yellow indicates my ability to search for the what would be searchName in my python code. Using the find feature in excel, and find indicates that there is a value here. However my python code does not produce the correct result. I have indicated an example of what I am doing with excel in the screenshot below.
Find Feature in Excel
I have included the output to my terminal when adding the print feature after search name below. Everything looks correct, except for the way that the search determines 'Found' or 'Not Found'. What am I missing?
Searching 'M-023-DXP' in ['TAPE,ELEC,76455A17,MCMSTR' 'TAP,8305A63,MCMSTR'    
 'TAPE,REFLCTV,BRT-TVHG-2X2,AL ELEC' ... 'PLUG, 23-A'
 'BTTRY,ALKLN,22M705,GRNGR' 'DRV,22B-D2P3N104,AB']


As mentioned, Prima facie the code looks like it should work. You could assist by doing some debugging, even adding a line like print(f"Searching '{searchName}' in {df['Description'].values}") after the searchName= line to see what your searching for in what list values. A minimum working example should be something you could quickly create, needs only one or two rows which can share details of (what values are in the cells) so others have a better idea of your working data. It might even help you see where the issue is.

Thank you for this insight, I have added this feature to my initial post, and I am working on uploading a watered down version of my excel file.

I'm confused; You get the text you want to search for from the Sheet 'Parts' in column 1 [A] (which appears has no header row). An example search text is 'H25136'. Then search for this text in the 'DESCRIPTION' Column of the Sheet 'BE01' which seems is supposed to be like the tabulated data in the question ref 'Found Object'. It would seem you want to search the 'Item ID' column. Also the 'BE101' data doesn't match the other screen shot of  searching using Excel Find. Also also the printed debug data at the end is a different search again though the search text 'M-023-DXP' isn't in that list

I have a list of recommended spare parts that I pulled from another document, consisting of 265 part numbers that are provided by the manufacturer, which is the 'Item ID' column. This is added to our system, when they are added as parts in our system, contained in that 'DESCRIPTION' Column of the Sheet 'BE01'. As a result I want to use Item ID to determine if that part number that should be contained in one of the cells in the 'DESCRIPTION' Column. However the caveat to this is that it will be surrounded by other text and not always in the same place.

After talking to one of my colleagues, I believe what I am trying to achieve is a regex style of search, that parses the data so I can find the part number within a description.

After looking into regex more I am not finding anything regarding regex that allows me to pass variables into objects. Any resources that show how to pass variables into objects would be greatly appreciated. From what I have gathered there is no was to dynamically adapt regex methods, so either you have to hard code your values you are trying to find, or you have to continually trigger an input pop-up and manually type out the values you are searching for in your input box.

I've tried to run your code and it seemed to work fine.
As you didn't provide the contents of the Excel file, I've made it on my own.
I think you need to print 'searchName' and df['Description'].values in the for loop and get a hint from them.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
